# Symfony - Find asset name with assetic

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic, symfony-3.1

I would like to know the names of my assets in a controller. I use assetic, so the assets names are random.

For example for my css, in my Twig I have:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite'
        'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        'assets/css/core.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

The result:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://local.example.com/css/c491e8f-285c78f.css" />`

Now, I would like to find the name `c491e8f-285c78f.css` automatically in my controller. 
I tried:

```
var_dump($this->get('assetic.asset_manager')->getNames(),
         $this->get('assetic.asset_manager')->get('c491e8f')->getTargetPath());
```

The result:

```
array(3) {
    [0] => string(7) "c491e8f"
    [1] => string(7) "b011b98"
    [2] => string(7) "f4e7a09"
}
string(35) "_controller/css/c491e8f-285c78f.css"
```

It's not bad, but I have cheated to find the "c491e8f" name... How I can know it's my css asset name ? And how I can find automatically the asset path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you read the source code of bundle `kriswallsmith/assetic` you realize that it's not trivial to get the names of you assets
(assets have really unique names) and they are in the `getNames()` array in order of appeararance in the templates.

One of the solutions is to *Using Named Assets*

http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#using-named-assets

in config.yml:

```
assets:
    bootstrap_and_core:
        inputs:
            - 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            - 'assets/css/core.css'
```

*you will probably also need to run the command_`php app/console assetic:dump`*

and then:

```
var_dump($this->get('assetic.asset_manager')->get('bootstrap_and_core')->getTargetPath());

string 'assetic/bootstrap_and_core.css' (length=30)
```

**Names:**

```
var_dump($this->get('assetic.asset_manager')->getNames());

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'bootstrap_and_core' (length=18)
```

**Twig:**

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite'
        '@bootstrap_and_core'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Also note:**
    you don't have to use `{{ asset(asset_url) }}` - it would be enough to `{{ asset_url }}`